# How to set the right display scaling factor?

Tags: resolution, release-jolnir

I just installed elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir and are trying to setup the screen resolution.

I've got the 5K LG screen which has a native resolution of 5120x2880. My first thought were to choose 2560x1440 and use the 2x scaling option. That option wasn't availble in the settings but I DuckDuckGo'd and used xrandr to add the 2560x1440 resolution.

Unfortunately the UI is way to big. I went ahead and added 5120x2880 and now the UI is the right size but not sharp anymore.

How do I keep UI the right size but double the resolution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that this was a setting in Parallels Desktop that restricted the full resolution to the virtual machine.

You have to change Hardware/Graphics/Resolution to 'More space' instead of 'Scaled'.